# Addressing individual distributed RGB LEDs

Tags: arduino, i2c, communication

I want to have a set of RGB LEDs and to be able to define the color for each one individually. The LEDs will be in different locations but in the same room. Some solutions I'm considering with wired and wireless approaches:

- Each LED has its own Arduino (or similar), all Arduino are connected with I2C, the "main" Arduino sets the color for each
- Each LED has its own ESP8266 (or similar), through wifi, the "main" board set the color for each
- Use TTGO with color display, instead of LED I can set the color on the display, wifi also.

Is there any simple solution? Are there LED strips where each LED can be addressed independently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WS2812B](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwihrP-UhILoAhWHVBUIHZy0CwAQFjASegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0pjyiTjDziRpVtiPKGdmRB) is exactly what you want. It is most commonly seen on colour strips and often sold with a controller and remote.

There are oodles of articles about them and how to control them with a microcontroller study as those embedded in the Arduino platform.

Comment: I've checked their specs and it seems really interesting. I will order some of these. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a de-facto standard to control RGB LEDs called WS2812. WS2812 is a serial protocol that supports daisy-chain connections between LEDs, allowing you to set the color of each one on the chain with just one digital signal.

You can buy WS2812-compatible LEDs individually or as strips. They're popular and cheap. Unsurprisingly, there are many WS2812 Arduino projects to be found. And there's ones for ESP8266 too.

If you want a wired solution that's industrial-grade, consider using DMX512 instead. DMX512 is based on RS-485 and there are many good, robust solutions for building and theatrical lighting.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by making a "pros and cons" list first.

Consider this example pros/cons list for going with wired over wireless:

**Pros:**

- Lower cost (each LED does not need a wireless module)
- Faster to develop (potentially less complicated than selecting or developing a wireless protocol)
- Single point of control
- Power distribution can be centralized

**Cons:**

- Physical wire must be ran to each LED; could cause problems routing wire around objects or entrances in a room
- Depending on distance, power and/or data transmission could be a problem resulting in other costs or added components
- Units cannot be relocated easily without extending or modifying wire

---

You state that the LEDs will be in different locations throughout a room, but I'm unsure if you mean that LED ***strips*** or single LEDs will be in different locations. If you're using LED strips, then (as other answers have pointed out) WS281x LEDs with embedded PWM drivers are a fine solution. Data is sent serially down the line and each LED displays an individually-controlled color.

If you're using individual LEDs, it might make more sense to implement a wireless solution if, as I envision, a dozen single LEDs are located around a room. Routing wire to each around a room could be a chore. You'll have to do a cost/benefit analysis for your application.

As an example, I have a 60-LED strip that I control with an [Adafruit Feather M0 with on-board WINC 1500 WiFi](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3010). It attaches to my wireless network and serves up a very basic HTTP REST API that I control via a browser or app. It would be relatively easy to add more LEDs, but I would need to evaluate whether physically wiring them together was "better" than purchasing more controllers. If the second unit was going to be very far away, I'd have to contend with power and data transmission problems. On the other hand, adding another controller is rather more expensive than a couple of meters of wire.

I'm not endorsing nor affiliated with [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/), but I can recommend checking out some of their LED offerings since they have the WS281x style LEDs (called Neopixels) along with quite a lot of helpful and educational write-ups.